# Azure SQL Server user roles

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, user-permissions

I have two servers on my Azure subscriptions that I use for SQL Server dbs with my adf work

I have initially created both of them, and created the same user id to use with both - one server for dev, another one for prod.  As far as I remember, both of the users were created in the same way .. but .. it is only  my recollection.

Now on the dev server I created the user defined type in the database "DBName" - a table type, and a stored procedure where it is used.  Everything works OK
Then, when I attempt to do the same on the prod, using scripts, I am able to create the type, and see it in the object explorer.  However, when creating stored procedure, I get this error

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Procedure myStoredProcedure, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 5]
> Cannot find the type 'MyTypeTBL', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Is it a user role causing this on the prod server?  Is there way to compare the user roles between the two servers to make sure they are the same?
I have a datafactory pipelines running in prod, using that user successfully for running stored procedures and selecting data.  I was also creating tables and stored procedures with that user.
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you authenticating as the same user to create both the objects, or as different users?

Comment: As the same user .... I am being logged in as the same user .. in prod.
I did the same in dev where it works

Comment: Do you have fewer permissions in production?

Comment: It is vaugely possible ... as I mentioned, to my recollection, I created user in the same way, but it is ONLY to my recollection,

I don't know how to verify it ..

I am ab le to create the type and use it - it is a table type, I can declare a variable of that type, and insert data into it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, why or how this is a case, but I resolved it this way:

I found a sql file where I was saving commands I ran, so I had the following

```
CREATE USER [azuser] 
WITH PASSWORD = 'myPasswd',
DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo; 

-- 2) - add user to role(s) in db 
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [azuser]; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [azuser];
ALTER ROLE [db_accessadmin] ADD MEMBER [azuser];
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [azuser];
```

That means, I ran those commands before when initiating everything
I added the following and got the problem resolved.

```
ALTER ROLE [db_ddladmin] ADD MEMBER [azuser];
-- Add user to the database owner role
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'azuser'
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[MyTypeTBL]
TO azuser;  
GO
```